# Retrieve xml doc comments programmatically

Tags: .net, xml, documentation

Visual Studio does it; Reflector does it; and now I want to as well :)

I want to retrieve the XML documentation for some members in some framework assemblies (i.e. `mscorlib.dll`, `System.dll`, etc). I assume this would involve:

- finding the XML file for the assembly,
- navigating to the appropriately named child element, and
- retrieving the desired items (`<summary>`, `<remarks>`, etc)

Where are the XML files kept for framework assemblies? Any points on deciphering the XMLDOC naming scheme? Are there any libraries out there that will make this process easier?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Find xml**

For assembly.dll it is named as assembly.xml, but installed by Framework SDK, Runtime itself doesn't contain .xml files. Users do not need API documentation.

Location is a bit more complex. It can be side by side with the dll, in the subdirectory named after current locale (e.g. C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\en) or even  in some weird directory nearby. I would suggest searching for it in the way runtime looks for satellite assemblies.

**Find element**

To find element, you should prepare so called "xml-doc ID" from the metadata. AFAIR it is documented in C# language spec, and a bit in MSDN. See [Processing XML documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fsbx0t7x.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

Based on [Ilya's response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230925/retrieve-xml-doc-comments-programmatically#231005):

**Find xml**

[.NET fallback locations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sb6a8618.aspx#cpconpackagingdeployingresourcesanchor1) (ignoring GAC and other irrelevant subdirectories)

```
static FileInfo GetXmlDocFile( Assembly assembly ) {
  string assemblyDirPath = Path.GetDirectoryName( assembly.Location );
  string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension( assembly.Location ) +".xml";

  return GetFallbackDirectories( CultureInfo.CurrentCulture )
    .Select( dirName => CombinePath( assemblyDirPath, dirName, fileName ) )
    .Select( filePath => new FileInfo( filePath ) )
    .Where( file => file.Exists )
    .First( );
}

static IEnumerable<string> GetFallbackDirectories( CultureInfo culture ) {
  return culture
    .Enumerate( c => c.Parent.Name != c.Name ? c.Parent : null )
    .Select( c => c.Name );
}

static IEnumerable<T> Enumerate<T>( this T start, Func<T, T> next ) {
  for( T item = start; !object.Equals( item, default(T) ); item = next( item ) )
    yield return item;
}

static string CombinePath( params string[] args ) {
  return args.Aggregate( Path.Combine );
}
```

**Find element**

[Processing XML Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fsbx0t7x.aspx)

```
static XElement GetDocMember( XElement docMembers, MemberInfo member ) {
  string memberId = GetMemberId( member );
  return docMembers.Elements( "member" )
    .Where( e => e.Attribute( "name" ).Value == memberId )
    .First( );
}

static string GetMemberId( MemberInfo member ) {
  char memberKindPrefix = GetMemberPrefix( member );
  string memberName = GetMemberFullName( member );
  return memberKindPrefix + ":" + memberName;
}

static char GetMemberPrefix( MemberInfo member ) {
  return member.GetType( ).Name
    .Replace( "Runtime", "" )[0];
}

static string GetMemberFullName( MemberInfo member ) {
  string memberScope = "";
  if( member.DeclaringType != null )
    memberScope = GetMemberFullName( member.DeclaringType );
  else if( member is Type )
    memberScope = ((Type)member).Namespace;

  return memberScope + "." + member.Name;
}
```

**Example use**

```
Type type = typeof( string );

var file = GetXmlDocFile( type.Assembly );
var docXml = XDocument.Load( file.FullName );
var docMembers = docXml.Root.Element( "members" );

var member = type.GetProperty( "Length" );
var docMember = GetDocMember( docMembers, member );
```

Comment: Note that this only supports simple members (i.e. fields and properties), and does not support method arguments.

Answer (score 2):

I maintain the [Jolt.NET](http://jolt.codeplex.com) project on CodePlex and have implemented a feature that performs this very task.  Please refer to the [Jolt](http://jolt.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Jolt) library for more information.

In essence, the library allows you to programatically locate and query an XML doc comments file for an assembly using the metadata types in `System.Reflection` (i.e. `MethodInfo`, `PropertyInfo`, etc...).

Answer (score 2):

Try [DocsByReflection](https://github.com/giacomelli/DocsByReflection).

```
// From method.
var methodInfo = typeof(Stub).GetMethod("MethodWithGenericParameter");
var methodDoc = DocsService.GetXmlFromMember(methodInfo);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a ready-made library that will allow you to do just that: NuDoc http://kzu.to/nudoc

Reading the entire documentation on mscorlib for example, would be as simple as:

```
var members = Reader.Read(typeof(string).Assembly);
```

And you can later process the results using a simple visitor, as shown on the site.

I'm in the process of leveraging that library to generate an API site using markdown for hosting in GitHub, ideally automatically on every build, and maybe even for the wiki so it can updated and round-tripped to the code :).

Comment: The page seems to have moved to http://www.cazzulino.com/NuDoq/. GitHub: https://github.com/kzu/NuDoq.

Answer (score 0):

The XML file is named exactly like the assembly's file, except for the different 'xml' extension and must be located in the same directory as the assembly itself.

Can't help you with the other two questions, though. AFAIK, you're on your own...